# ASP.NET - ajax call return response but not show in table

Tags: asp.net, ajax

i have a problem i want to get the data from api and show in table.
i see the response in Network tab in chrome but nothing show in my table and i try do some changes but still not work.

how i can fix it?

thanks!!!

my code:

inside Api folder -> TestNewsController:

```
namespace AutomationTool.Api
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TestNewsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public TestNewsController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/TestNews
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<TestNew>>> GetTestNews()
        {
            return await _context.TestNews.ToListAsync();
        }           
    }
}
```

inside Pages folder -> AllTests -> Index.cshtml:

```
@page
@model AutomationTool.Pages.AllTests.IndexModel
@{    
}

<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Customers</a>
    </li>      

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane container active p-0" id="home" style="margin-top:15px;">
        <table id="customerTable" class="table table-bordered">
            <thead class="thead-dark text-white">
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Domain</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>TestPlan</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts{    
    <script>


            $(function () {
                $.ajax("/api/TestNews",
                    { method: "get" })
                    .then(function (response) { // get the response (json data)
                        console.dir(response);
                        $('#cutomerTable')  // take the id from table tag
                            .DataTable({
                                data: response, // the data of this table
                                columns: [
                                    { "data": "Id" },
                                    { "data": "Clipro" },
                                    { "data": "Name" },
                                    { "data": "TestPlan" },
                                    { "data": "EndPoint" },
                                    { "data": "Status" }
                                ]
                            });
                    });
            });



    </script>
```

or i try something like that:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {  
        $("#cutomerTable").DataTable({  
            "ajax": {  
                "url": "@Url.Action("GetTestNews", "TestNews")",  
                "type": "GET",  
                "datatype": "json"  
            },  
            "columns": [  
                  { "data": "Id" },
                  { "data": "Clipro" },
                  { "data": "Name" },
                  { "data": "TestPlan" },
                  { "data": "EndPoint" },
                  { "data": "Status" }
            ]  
        });
```

Comment: In ajax you have passed wrong Table id. You have passed 'cutomerTable' instead of 'customerTable'.

Comment: i change but still not working.

Comment: i edit the post, see in the end that what i try to do when i want to click on specific nav button and the table will show.

Comment: public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<TestNew>>> GetTestNews() this line has something missing. If you are getting the data, you must create a table instance and pass it as a parameter, and then return it into the view.

Answer (score 0):

**I am assuming you are using Code-First Approach.**

Your controller code is missing few things:

For instance, your code:

// GET: api/TestNews

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<TestNew>>> GetTestNews()
    {
        return await _context.TestNews.ToListAsync();
    }
```

In order to get the records from the database, you must create table instance and pass it in View, like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<TestNew>>> GetTestNews(ClassName myObj)
    {
         await _context.TestNews.ToListAsync();
         return View(myObj);
    }
```

Here the **ClassName** in parameter is the actual class name required for DbSet in DbContext class (where you have getter and setter properties defined)

**Next:** Your View page doesn't have Razor syntax, then how will the browser know how to render the View.

So instead of this:

```
<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane container active p-0" id="home" style="margin-top:15px;">
    <table id="customerTable" class="table table-bordered">
        <thead class="thead-dark text-white">
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Domain</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>TestPlan</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Change it to something like this:

```
<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane container active p-0" id="home" style="margin-top:15px;">
    <table id="customerTable" class="table table-bordered">
        <thead class="thead-dark text-white">
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Domain</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>TestPlan</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        @foreach(ModelName obj in Model){
        <tbody>@obj.PropertyNames</tbody>
          }
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

This is just an idea that how it should proceed. Since you have not shared your Views completely I am unable to help you out with exact answer.

Hope this direction will give you a direction. :)